# Как реализовать простое изоморфное приложение?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, клиент-сервер

В теории я понял что изоморфное приложение это когда вместо REST API c с сервера отдаются Rendered куски html? Если нет то поправьте.
Пока нашел только теорию изоморфных приложений. Но как на практике склеить простой пример как например Hello world найти не могу.
Как сделать простейшее изоморфоное приложение? На NodeJS + Angular например?

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить простым языком, “изоморфность” состоит в том, что мы можем использовать один и тот же код как на стороне клиента, так и на стороне сервера.
Смотри [сюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/259625/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.